# React-map-gl transition error which crashes the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-map-gl, deck.gl, deck.js

I am having an issue with my map where a certain trackpad gesture crashes the map. The error that is shown upon this is attached below.

[Transition error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2wRO.png)

As seen in the image, it requires a position prop which I could not find in any documentation of react-map-gl or deck.gl. I am not sure what this error is about.